# Script438 in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a user defined function being called like this:

```
window.showFrame(ID)
```

Now, it works on if I have compatibility mode on, but when turned off, the error 'Object does't support property or method 'showFrame' is thrown.

Is this feature deprecated or am I misusing the window object?

Comment: Check if the `showFrame` function is defined.

Comment: Agreed with @Halcyon. I'm not familiar with a standard `showFrame` function that comes with Javascript. Is it possible for you to do a search for `showFrame` and see if there are any results? If so, update your question with that function?

Comment: showFrame is a user-defined function.

Comment: do you try to call this function without window? do you call this function before or after it is loaded in the DOM?

Comment: when calling this without window, I get 'showFrame is undefined'. the function is being called after the DOM is loaded; it is triggered by an onclick event.